# Custom Ajax Based Search Form

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm trying to create a custom search form that uses ajax to perform the actual search and return the located objects as html.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
function example_module_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
   $form['title'] = array( 
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#value' => '',
   );
   $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'example_module_search_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'bottom',
        'method' => 'replace',
      ),
      '#value' => t('Submit'),
   );
   return $form;
}

function example_module_search_callback($form, $form_state) {
   $title = $form_state['input']['title'];
   $objects = db_query('SELECT * FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type && title = :title', array(':type' => 'object', ':title' => $title))->fetchAll();
   $output = '';
   foreach($objects as $object):
     $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:200px;">'.$object->title.'</div>';
   endforeach;
   return $output;
}
```

The above works fine the first time I submit the form, but in subsequent requests the `$form_state['input']['title']` is always the same?

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or perhaps there's a better approach. The reason why I would like to implement my own search form is that the form will have a very large set of controls which values will be used to query the database.

Comment: You should pass $form_state by reference

Comment: @xurshid29 only if he plans to write to it. And actually passing $form by reference sometimes makes sense too.

Comment: I tested modified version of your code with core search module and it works fine.. And There is wrong line in your code I think: '#value' - used by button, hidden, image_button, submit, token, value elements.

Comment: There is no "`replace`" method according to official API [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7). It's "`replaceWith`" that you're looking for. Also, even though it doesn't matter for your case/code, you shouldn't really set `#value` on a textfield on your form function, you should use `#default_value`.

Comment: you should move the code that searches the DB and builds the result into your form function and insert the results into `$form`

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Drupal, the ajax callback is business logic free. You should associate your title (ie string) directly in the form, when ajax had run.
I use this :

```
function contact_contact_search_form($form, &$form_state) {

$string = '';

//Retrive the string value
if (isset($form_state['values'])) { // Does ajax ran ?
   $string = $form_state['values']['string'];
}

$form['string'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Name'),
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'contact_contact_search_ajax',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'none',
  ),
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
);


// Display the result in the form, but should work if the results are outside of your form
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="search-table">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#markup' => contact_contact_display_searches($string),
);


return $form;
}


function contact_contact_search_ajax(&$form, &$form_state) {


   $commandes[] = ajax_command_replace('#search-table',drupal_render($form['table']));

   return array(
     '#type' => 'ajax',
     '#commands' => $commandes,
   );
}


// Create your table
function contact_contact_display_searches($string) {
// The query
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
      ->fields('n')
      ->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');
      ->range(0, 20)
      ->execute()->fetchAll();

 // Prepare and clean the results
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $rows[$result->nid] = array(
      'type' => check_plain($types[$result->type]->name),
      'title' => l(check_plain($result->title), 'node/' . $result->nid),
      'email' => check_plain($result->field_pers_email_email),
  );
}

// Simple table theming
$out = theme('table', array(
    'header' => array(t('Type de contenu'), t('Intitulé'), t('email')),
    'rows' => $rows,
    'empty' => t('Aucun résultat avec ces critères de recherche')
        )
  );
}
return $out;


}
```

Comment: Hello. Could you please add some description about how this code is supposed to solve OP's problem? And maybe add come comments in the code, too?

Comment: I don't quite get this, can you add the code for `contact_contact_search_ajax()` and `contact_contact_display_searches()` as well?

Comment: The code have been added, use the scroll